# Compare 2 different tables columns from 2 different databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a requirement to compare different tables' columns from 2 different databases, in order to add columns to the master tables based on the requirement.

For example:

Assume in master database I have created one table like:

```
create table test(id int,name varchar(10))
```

Assume in test database I have created one table like

```
create table testings(id int,name varchar(20), sal int)
```

now I have to compare 2 table columns

I don't want to use red-gate tools.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 11):

Is it just red-gate tools you don’t want to use or basically any third party tool? Why not, even if you don’t have the budget to buy you can still use this in trial mode to get the job done?

We’ve been using [Apex Diff](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_diff.aspx) tool but there are many more out there.

With so many tools available you can probably run all one by one in trial mode for months…

Knowing system tables and how to do this natively is great but it’s just too time consuming...

Answer (score 9):

You can use the [**`EXCEPT`** or **`INTERSECT`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx) set operators for this. Like so:

```
SELECT id, name FROM master.dbo.test
EXCEPT  -- or INTERSECT
SELECT id, name FROM test.dbo.testings
```

This will give you:

> - **EXCEPT:** returns any distinct values from the left query that are not
>     also found on the right query.
> - **INTERSECT:** returns any distinct values that are returned by both the
>     query on the left and right sides of the INTERSECT operand.

In your case, since you want to select from two different databases, you have to use a fully qualified table names. They have to be in the form **`database.schema.object_name`**.

**Update:** If you want compare the two tables columns' names, not the data itself, you have to work with the metadata tables to compare the columns' names the same way with `EXCEPT`.

For instance, suppose you have two databases:

- **`Test`** database contains the table:

  ```
  create table test(id int, name varchar(10), dep varchar(50));
  ```

  and another database:
- **`anotherdatabase`** database contains the table:

  ```
  create table testings(id int,name varchar(20), sal int);
  ```

And you want to compare the two tables' columns and get the tables that don't exist in the other table, in our example you need to get `sal` and `dep`.

Then you can do this:

```
SELECT ColumnName
FROM
(
    SELECT  c.name "ColumnName"
    FROM test.sys.tables t
    INNER JOIN test.sys.all_columns c 
            ON t.object_id = c.object_id
    INNER JOIN test.sys.types ty 
            ON c.system_type_id = ty.system_type_id
    WHERE t.name = 'test'
    EXCEPT
    SELECT  c.name
    FROM anotherdatabase.sys.tables t
    INNER JOIN anotherdatabase.sys.all_columns c 
            ON t.object_id = c.object_id
    INNER JOIN anotherdatabase.sys.types ty 
            ON c.system_type_id = ty.system_type_id
    WHERE t.name = 'testings'
) t1
UNION ALL
SELECT ColumnName
FROM
(
    SELECT  c.name ColumnName
    FROM anotherdatabase.sys.tables t
    INNER JOIN anotherdatabase.sys.all_columns c  
            ON t.object_id = c.object_id
    INNER JOIN anotherdatabase.sys.types ty      
            ON c.system_type_id = ty.system_type_id
    WHERE t.name = 'testings'
    EXCEPT
    SELECT  c.name
    FROM test.sys.tables t
    INNER JOIN test.sys.all_columns c 
            ON t.object_id = c.object_id
    INNER JOIN test.sys.types ty 
            ON c.system_type_id = ty.system_type_id
    WHERE t.name = 'test'
) t2;
```

This should give you:

[image]

**Note that:** I joined the tables:

- [**`databasename.sys.tables`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187406%28v=sql.100%29.aspx), and
- [**`databasename.sys.all_columns`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177522.aspx)

with the table:

- [**`databasename.systypes`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188021%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

to get only those columns that have the same data type. If you didn't joined this table, then if two columns have the same name but different data type, they would be the same.

Comment: Hi Mahmoud Gamel , thank you for giving reply , remember that always set operators works on row wise not column wise. my requirement  is i have to compare 2 table columns if any table have less columns than another one i have to identify that column name and i have to add it. i hope u under stood.

Comment: @user1694000 - Sorry for misunderstanding. So, you want to get column names tat doesn't present in any of those. Right? Just column names.

Comment: Many thanks Mahmoud Gamal , Problem resolved by using sqldatacompare tool. actually i am not interested to use 3 rd party tools but i have to check 1326 tables so it takes time to pass every table that's y i used 3 rd party tool . than any way many many thanks for ur co-operation

Comment: Many thanks Mahmoud Gamal , Problem resolved by using sqldatacompare tool. actually i am not interested to use 3 rd party tools but i have to check 1326 tables so it takes time to pass every table that's y i used 3 rd party tool . coming to our proble we can i identify columns with the above code very easily  but how can i know that column is from which table . i.e it is showing only columns details but not along with table names , so the above result is not at all useful to me because how can i find the column name belongs to perticuler table . than any way many many thanks for ur help.

Comment: EXCEPT: returns any distinct values from the left query that are also found on the right query.

Answer (score 1):

To compare columns use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` table in a SQL SERVER.

This is the exmaple:

```
select column_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME='your_table_name1'
except
select column_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME='your_table_name2'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a GPL Java program I wrote for comparing data in any two tables, with a common key and common columns, across any two heterogeneous databases using JDBC: https://sourceforge.net/projects/metaqa/

It intelligently forgives (numeric, string and date) data type differences by reducing them to a common format. The output is a sparse tab delimited file with .xls extension for use in a spreadsheet.